# Remeasuring portion of NHD route system?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, linear-referencing, nhd

How do I remeasure a portion of the NHD route system? So that it measures continuous through each confluence, that is, if 0 station is at the first confluence then when we reach the next confluence it continues to measure up through both reaches. All distances can be measure back to the first confluence.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.3.1, I can use 10.2-10.4